# What could prevent me from accepting an answer to my question?

Tags: support

I noticed that after some events I cannot accept the answer to my question for some time. What are those events and what time delays are? 
I assume that events could be either posting answer, editing answer or posting comments.

Comment: There is only *one* limit: you have to wait until your question is 15 minutes old at least.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot accept any answer until 15 minutes after you have asked the question.

You cannot accept *your own answer* until 48 hours after you have asked the question.

There are no other limitations on accepting an answer; posting an answer, editing an answer, or commenting do not extend the time at which an answer can be accepted.